# Unable to add new row in table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add new row in table on user side.
I have done it, but it enters new row only first time, when you clicks on add row button second time, nothing happens.

```js
function insTableRow(tableID) {
  var x = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var get_row = x.rows[2];
  get_row.style.display = '';
  console.log(get_row);
  $("#" + tableID + " tbody").append(get_row);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i id="add" class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x fa-fw" onclick="insTableRow('educationTable')"></i>
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered order-list" id="educationTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Institute Name</th>
      <th>Qualification</th>
      <th>Admission Date</th>
      <th>Graduation Date</th>
      <th>Degree Scanned Image</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><i id="add" class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x fa-fw" onclick="delTableRow('educationTable')"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2kw71kf/4/)

any idea, why its not appending new row on second time ?

Comment: because it's not a new row: it's always the same one

Comment: Also you have assigned the id "number" multiple times. That's not a good practise. Try to give unique ID to each element.

Comment: there's an important difference between the example in the question you posted before and this one: you're not cloning the row. That means, you're not creating a new row, you're always appending the same one in the end, so obviously you don't see another one appearing

Comment: you need to create a new row and then append it. use this link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Comment: @Umesh just FYI, don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is ***far*** more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow

Comment: Use a clone function

  function insTableRow(tableID) {
    var x=document.getElementById(tableID);    
    $("#main_row").clone().appendTo("#"+tableID+" tbody");
  }

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_clone.asp for refrence

Comment: @GurmeetSingh [*Bangs head against wall*] http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is because you're selecting the same row and appending it on every click. You're not creating a new row. To fix this you can clone the row and append that new instance.

Also note that you should avoid using outdated `on*` event handlers in your HTML. As you've already included jQuery in the page you can use that to attach your events outside the HTML. In addition you can use a delegated event handler on the `delete` icon to remove the clicked row. Try this:

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  var $row = $('#educationTable').find('tr:last');
  $row.clone().insertBefore($row).show();
});

$('#educationTable').on('click', '.delete', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i id="add" class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered order-list" id="educationTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Institute Name</th>
      <th>Qualification</th>
      <th>Admission Date</th>
      <th>Graduation Date</th>
      <th>Degree Scanned Image</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" /></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" /></td>
      <td><i class="delete fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x fa-fw"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also note that I removed the repeated `id="number"` as it's invalid HTML to repeat the same `id` attribute across multiple elements. Use a class for that instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

Clone your Initial row to create new rows, rather than showing the `display:none` rows

```js
function insTableRow(tableID) {
  var x = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var get_row = $(x.rows[1]).clone();
  $("#" + tableID + " tbody").append(get_row);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i id="add" class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x fa-fw" onclick="insTableRow('educationTable')"></i>
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered order-list" id="educationTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Institute Name</th>
      <th>Qualification</th>
      <th>Admission Date</th>
      <th>Graduation Date</th>
      <th>Degree Scanned Image</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" /></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: While this works, you need to remember to clear the values in the row after cloning it